# I'm not finding the issue with my css @media query

Tags: css, mobile

tldr; I can't get `mobile.css` to work right on my site.

My site is `http://sweepsmeoffmyfeet.com`

My `mobile.css` file

```
/* CSS Document */

@media all and (min-width:401px) and (max-width:970px) {    
    body {  font-size:1em;}
    .headwrapper { width:100%;}
    .headwrapper .sitelogo{width: 100%;}
    .wrapper { width:100%;}
    .wrapper .container2{width:100%;display:block; }
    input:not([type]), input[type="url"]{width: 400px; height: 20px;}
    .crossborder .content{ width:100%; margin: 0 auto;}
    .boxHousing{width:48%;display:inline-block;}
    .siteHosted{max-width: 400px;}
    .card{width:400px;margin:10px auto;text-align:center;}
    .rules{max-width:400px;padding:5px; margin: 5px auto}
    .sideBar{width: 100%;display:block;}
}

@media all and (max-width:400px) {
    body {  font-size:1em;}
    .headwrapper { width:100%;}
    .headwrapper .sitelogo{width: 100%;}
    .crossborder .content{ width:100%; margin: 0 auto;}
    .wrapper { width:100%;}
    .wrapper .container2{width:100%;display:block; }
    input:not([type]), input[type="url"]{width: 300px;}
    .boxHousing{width:100%;display:block;}
    .container .content{display:block; margin-right: 0;width: 100%;}
    .siteHosted{ max-width: 300px;}
    .rules{max-width:300px;padding:5px; margin: 5px auto}
    .sideBar{width: 100%; display:block;}
}
```

I am attempting to change a few things for mobile views.

I have a large container that on normal screens, will display at 972[x wide, but I would like it to go to 100% on smaller screens.

I set up the css and uploaded it, but it doesn't seem to be detected. I even changed the background colors to see if they were getting picked up, but am having no luck.

I am very unfamiliar with doing this, so I am not sure exactly what I could be doing wrong. Could someone take a look and see what I'm doing wrong. I will tell you that I have been reading on it through google searches, and it appears as though I am doing what they're saying to, unless I'm just missing a piece of the puzzle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a file style.css called later than mobile.css in your <head> tag. This will override rules for an element from mobile.css if it is declared a value in style.css. So e.g. in style.css element with class .headwrapper is declared a width of 95%. Although in mobile.css you give it a width of 100% it will be overwritten by style.css

Comment: cool. I'll give that a try. I'll let you know how it pans out!

Comment: Yeah I checked your site a couple of minutes ago, it's looking good! No problem, glad to help :)

Comment: @Bastiaan - Post the solution as an answer. And Zach, please, mark it down as accepted, for the sake of the comunity

Comment: @LcSalazar I didn't know if my remark was large enough for an answer. I did add it now, thanks for the input!

Comment: @Bastiaan - No problem... If it is a working solution to the question, it's a valid answer... It does not matter the length

Comment: I couldn't mark it until it was posted as an actual answer instead of a comment.

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a file style.css called later than mobile.css in your  tag. This will override rules for an element from mobile.css if it is declared a value in style.css.

So e.g. in style.css element with class .headwrapper is declared a width of 95%. Although in mobile.css you give it a width of 100% it will be overwritten by style.css.

Moving the call for the mobile.css stylesheet under style.css in the `<head>` will fix it.